# How to Create Find in Notepad in C#

Tags: c#, find

I am trying to create a notepad like application in C# by using a Textbox.
I want to implement find function in it. I want an ability to search the text entered in textbox of Find form in textbox of Form1 and then highlight it.
Please help i am unable to do it

Form1.cs

```
    private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Find f = new Find();

        f.Show();

    }

    public void find()
    {

        int idx = 0;
        while((idx=textBox1.Text.IndexOf(text))!=1)
        {
             textBox1.Select();//Select the text which are found
        }
    }
```

Find.cs

```
    public partial class Find : Form
    {
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    public Find()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Cancelbutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Findbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f.text =textBox1.Text;
        f.find();

    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the `in notepad in c#` - do you mean a TextBox or do you mean tacking something onto NotePad? I think your probably off searching for things like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18050/C-search-engine-refactored-to-search-Word-PDF-an

Comment: in c# i was trying create a notepad,which has a textbox

Comment: I updated the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: thanks for updating it,please help me to search the text of one textbox with other textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the start and length parameter in the "Select" method. For Example:

```
textBox1.Select(idx, text.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only highlight one section of data at a time with the standard TextBox. Try [FastColourTextbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) if you want better support.

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
   {
      textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
      textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for reply of selecting the text,but how to search the text in textbox ,above code in my question doesn't work i am unable to serach i get index (idx)= -1